# Batch file to collect UUID and Serial number

Tags: batch-file

I have been using this batch file to collect the Serial number and UUID number and output to a CSV and now it no longer works.

```
@echo off
set outputfile="Y:\HP\UUDI.csv"
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic csproduct Get "UUID" /value') do SET CSPRODUCT=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic bios get serialnumber /value') do SET SERIAL=%%i
echo UUID,Serial,>>%outputfile%
echo %CSPRODUCT%,%SERIAL%,>>%outputfile%
```

If someone can look at this file and help me understand what went wrong I would appreciate it

Comment: No longer works really isn't a description of a problem.  Maybe you could provide more detail as to what doesn't work.  The code you provided seems to work just fine when I tested it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what did you mean by "No Longer Works" ? Please be more explicit when you ask a question !

here is a test and tell me if this works or not on your side and i will edit this aswer according to your response !

---

```bat
@echo off
set "outputfile=%~dp0UUDI.csv"
@for /f %%i in (
    'wmic csproduct Get "UUID" /value ^& wmic bios get serialnumber /value'
) do (
    @for /f %%j in ("%%i") do set "%%j" & echo "%%j"
)
echo UUID,SerialNumber>"%outputfile%"
echo %UUID%,%SERIALNumber%>>"%outputfile%"
If exist "%outputfile%" Start "" "%outputfile%" & Exit
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see for your provided code to change its behavior, is that which was commented already by Mofi. That is, you've somehow caused the location of `WMIC.exe` to have been removed from the `%Path%` environment.

I have decided to provide an alternative method of achieving your goal using your chosen command utility `WMIC.exe`, and using its full path, to prevent such a reliance in future.

The WMIC command is traditionally one of the slower ones, so this method invokes it only once. All you should need to do is `Echo` your commands, currently on lines `12`and `14`, each separated as in line `13`. If any of your commands requires to `Get` more than one property, you should separate those with caret escaped commas, e.g. `Get Property1^,Property2`. The results, *(subject to line/environment length limitations)*, will then be saved to variables, `%Title%`, and `%Record%`, which can later be output to a file outside of the loop. Note: all commands should use `/Value`, or the more correct, `/Format:List`.

Example, *(don't forget to adjust your output file path on line `4` as needed)*:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "outputfile=Y:\HP\UUDI.csv"

Set "WMIC=%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe"
Set "FIND=%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe"
Set "Title="
Set "Record="
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %%G In ('
    (
        Echo CSProduct Get UUID /Value
        ^&
        Echo BIOS Get SerialNumber /Value
    ^)
    ^| %WMIC% ^| %FIND% "="
') Do (If Not Defined Title (Set "Title=%%G") Else (
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        For /F "Tokens=*" %%I In ("!Title!") Do (EndLocal
            Set "Title=%%I,%%G"))
    If Not Defined Record (Set "Record=%%H") Else (
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        For /F "Tokens=*" %%I In ("!Record!") Do (EndLocal
            Set "Record=%%I,%%H")))
If Defined Title (  Echo %Title%
                    Echo %Record%) 1>"%outputfile%"
```